How to set ThreadsPerChild on Apache 2.4.46 - Wamp 3.2.3 with Http2
I have an Apache 2.4.46 server on wamp 3.2.3 with mpm_winnt_module active with the following configuration:
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

If I activate the mod_http2.so Apache doesn't start with the following error:
(OS 8)Not enough storage is available to process this command.  : AH00355: Child: CreateThread failed. Unable to create all worker threads. Created 0 of the 150 threads requested with the ThreadsPerChild configuration directive.

The system has total 8Gb of RAM with 60% free memory.
It is not clear why without http2 I have no error memory and the relationship of HTTP2 with

ThredsPerChild
ThreadStackSize

Thanks for help.
